# Update_Many Mongo Document with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo-3.x

I have a problem with mongo with a list of data.

I have some items in Mongo DB and I need to update some of them with different data.

Example,

in DB now I have:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e422a7c37c8d5c7f92add9"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 09:30:12.193452",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "8ee640883e8bce3ebed1dba8a0c6c7e5",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.5316912313644865",
            "processing_duration": 378.8
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e422b1c37c8d5c7f92addb"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 09:30:24.465770",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "b0384a99d40dfe6375d615689e02dfb2",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.7002104",
            "processing_duration": 49.75
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e422b1c37c8d5c7f92addc"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 09:30:17.535144",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "6d7b2640368d0b98dc81a3cde41b7ed9",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.6056733",
            "processing_duration": 35.61
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e422c5c37c8d5c7f92addf"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 09:30:42.515050",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "910be0727279462f6cca4d5b43093387",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.8142542043496809",
            "processing_duration": 17.57
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e423b5c37c8d5c7f92adf8"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 09:34:38.985356",
            "from_cache": true,
            "message_hash": "910be0727279462f6cca4d5b43093387",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.8142542043496809",
            "processing_duration": 1.08
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e42f6ec37c8d5c7f92af25"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 10:24:40.329178",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "ad2f8a932272db08debaff29cb8feb69",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.7841739770961472",
            "processing_duration": 14.71
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60e42f78c37c8d5c7f92af27"),
            "date": "2021-07-06 10:24:48.530278",
            "from_cache": false,
            "message_hash": "d8d6cbc88b02d4dc4adb465d76843c00",
            "predict_result": "Spam",
            "probability": "0.7841739770961472",
            "processing_duration": 5.93
        }
    ]
}
```

I get requests from the end-point and need to update "predict_result" some of them with different data.

I try to do so:

```
def update_many(self, ids: list, data):
    query = {
            '_id': {
                "$in": ids
            }
        }

    newvalues = {
            "$set":
                {
                    data
                }
        }

    self.collection.update_many(query, newvalues)
```

But it doesn't work.

Thnx a lot for helping!

Comment: The `data` need to be assigned to some `field`. See [update-many example](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update_many#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'data' is a python dict, you should use this:

```
def update_many(self, ids: list, data):
    query = {"_id": {"$in": ids}}
    newvalues = {"$set": data}
    self.collection.update_many(query, newvalues)
```

This would update the fields in 'data'.